# Eclipse password storage

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently learning Java and am starting to use file IO. For a random personal project, I would like a user to create an "account" with a password. I would like to store the information for later, but I would like to have a way to encrypt the password (something even very basic would work for now).

Any tips are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use some kind if hashing algorithm and store the resulting hash, compare the imputed hash with the stored hash. Look up something like md5 hash in java

Comment: That looks exactly like something that would be great to use. Thanks!

Comment: @GeoDude Please ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where something called [Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) comes in handy. Hash functions work by creating a hash key (integer value) from the original string using a function. The benefit of this is that you can check that a password is correct by checking whether the entered password is the same as the stored hash key, without actually knowing the password.

Creating your own hash function is something you wouldn't normally be expected to do as there are [secure hash functions available](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). Although you may want to play around with them for fun.

Comment: I've looked a little into this now and looks very promising. Thanks!